# Set default region in boto config

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am trying to set a default region for AWS web services, specifically dynamodb. This is my boto config

**.boto**

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = KEY
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET
[Boto]
autoscale_region_name = us-west-2
```

When I create table without using connection parameter, then the table is created in us-east-1 rather than us-west-2.

```
def create_table_ratings():
    '''
    Schema definition of table ratings
    '''
    ratings = Table.create('ratings', schema=[
        HashKey('user_id', data_type=NUMBER),
        RangeKey('photo_id', data_type=NUMBER)
    ], throughput={
        'read': 5,
        'write': 15,
    })
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify region for DynamoDb. You are specifying region for autoscale. Use the following setting instead:

```
[DynamoDB]
region = us-west-2
validate_checksums = True
```

Answer (score 0):

In more general you can use the [Boto] section to set defaults, such as for EC2

```
[Boto]
ec2_region_name = us-west-2
ec2_region_endpoint = ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```